# Can't configure active directory plugin for multiple subdomains in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, active-directory

Im trying to configure security in jenkins for users in multiple sub domains

our main domain controller is company1.ics and users are in company1corp.company1.ics and Department2.company1corp.company1.ics

I have configured Jenkins in the following way

domain name - company1corp.company1.ics and Department2.company1corp.company1.ics
domain controler -company1.ics

If i select test it says "ok" but when I try to add users it doesn't recognize anyone.  If I don't add any values for domain name and domain it will add the users for the first domain but not the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the incorrect setting for the Domain controller,  IT gave me a different name and its all working well now

Answer (score 0):

It works when I configured subdomains separed by comma.

E.g.:

1. Access Jenkins configure settings: /jenkins/configureSecurity/
2. In Domain name field put: company1corp.company1.ics,Department2.company1corp.company1.ics

It works for my company.